# Why are integers returning as hex?

Tags: solidity, javascript

I am implementing a simple smart contract in Solidity 0.5.9. One of the functions is called `getSummary()` which basically returns a summarized version of a vote:

```
function getSummary() public view returns (uint, uint, uint, address, bool) {
    return (
        reward,
        choices.length,
        votersCount,
        manager,
        pollActive
    );
}
```

I test this in Remix and get the results as I expect:

```
0: uint256: 9000000000000000
1: uint256: 2
2: uint256: 0
3: address: 0x1d174c79A9Fc825F2d625adEAa7035381D3a413e
4: bool: true
```

So far so good.

Now, I am working on a simple JavaScript frontend to display these results to the user, using `web3-1.0.0`, however I get the results in a weird format:

```
0: {…}
​​​
_ethersType: "BigNumber"
​​​
_hex: "0x1ff973cafa8000"
​​​
<prototype>: Object { fromTwos: fromTwos(), toTwos: toTwos(), abs: abs()
, … }
​​
1: {…}
​​​
_ethersType: "BigNumber"
​​​
_hex: "0x02"
​​​
<prototype>: Object { fromTwos: fromTwos(), toTwos: toTwos(), abs: abs()
, … }
​​
2: {…}
​​​
_ethersType: "BigNumber"
​​​
_hex: "0x00"
​​​
<prototype>: Object { fromTwos: fromTwos(), toTwos: toTwos(), abs: abs()
, … }
​​
3: "0x1d174c79A9Fc825F2d625adEAa7035381D3a413e"
​​
4: true
```

It looks like the `Boolean` and the `Address` are being returned in the correct format, whereas the integers are being returned as objects with the `_hex` property. I am pretty sure that I am seeing this for the first time and if I recall correctly, I haven't encountered such issue with previous smart contracts.

What am I doing wrong? Is this the expected behaviour? If yes, how can I correctly cast `uint` values from Solidity to display correctly on the frontend.

PS: I tried using `web3.utils.toAscii(val)` but values were transformed into funny characters, not to mention that this seems like a poor hack to do on every value I return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web3.js returns all `uint` types as `BigNumber` objects.

If you want to get the decimal string which represents the numeric value embedded in a `BigNumber` object, then you can call function [`toFixed`](https://mikemcl.github.io/bignumber.js/#toFix) on that object.

For example:

```
const [reward, length, votersCount, manager, pollActive] = await myContract.methods.getSummary();

console.log('reward:', reward.toFixed());
console.log('length:', length.toFixed());
console.log('votersCount:', votersCount.toFixed());
```